# Added another page in React but couldn't navigate

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

The LandingPage loads again when I try. The URL also shows localhost:3000/list# instead of localhost:3000/list. What am I doing wrong? 
Here's the index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { Router, Route, Switch, HashRouter, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import "assets/scss/material-kit-react.scss?v=1.8.0";

import Components from "views/Components/Components.js";
import LandingPage from "views/LandingPage/LandingPage.js";
import ProfilePage from "views/ProfilePage/ProfilePage.js";
import LoginPage from "views/LoginPage/LoginPage.js";
import ListPage from "views/ListPage/ListPage.js";
let hist = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(  
  <HashRouter history={hist}>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/components" component={Components} />
      <Route path="/profile-page" component={ProfilePage} />
      <Route path="/login-page" component={LoginPage} />
      <Route path="/" component={LandingPage} />
      <Route path="/list" component={ListPage} />
    </Switch>
  </HashRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Here is the button I wish to use to open the new page

```
      <Button
        style={styl}
        color="success"
        size="lg"
        href="/list"
        target="_blank"
        rel="noopener noreferrer"
      >
        <i className="fas fa-cogs" />
        Pick Parts
      </Button>
```

I have used the Material-UI kit by CreativeTim to begin, and haven't really changed anything apart from removing a youtube link from the button and addding /list, as well as creating a new view ListPage in the Views folder, giving the path to the page in index.js
It doesn't work. Neither do the login and profile pages. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to add something to make it work?

Comment: Dont you need to use the `Link` component that react-router brings (to redirect)?

Comment: Trying using `Link`s or `props.history.push` function.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using [React-Router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) which is a Frontend tool that *makes it look like* you are navigating between pages (you might adjust it, to actually navigate between pages with SSR and something like [Next.js](https://www.google.com/amp/s/nextjs.org/%3Famp%3D1)).

Actually you don't since no GET is performed & no new page is loaded when you navigate to another "page".

This way, if you try to access pages directly (trying to GET them), the request will fail since this page actually isn't served by any server.

In order to successfully navigate, you'd like to use [Link component](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/primary-components/navigation-or-route-changers) like `<Link to="/">Home</Link>` or `useHistory` [hook](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Hooks/usehistory) provided by React-Router.

If you use the later one you will be able to push directly in history array which might be more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a CodeSandbox with a working version of something very similar to your code.

https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-davinci-4467b

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import Login from "./Login";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Link to="/" style={{ marginRight: "10px" }}>
          Home
        </Link>
        <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
      </div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

> The URL also shows localhost:3000/list# instead of localhost:3000/list. What am I doing wrong?

Use `BrowserRouter` if you don't want those hashes in your URL.

Also, unless you have a specific reason for that, you don't need to create your own `browserHistory`. The `BrowserRouter` will do that for you.